# Get Google Apps user's used quota

Tags: reporting, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, quota

I've been trying to obtain a Google Apps user's used quota and I find that it is possible with Admin SDK Reports API. However, it seems that it can only give you information from two days ago and before. This is the error I obtain:

```
Reason: "invalid"
Code: "400"
Message: "Data for dates later than 2014-06-04 is not yet available. Please check back later"
Domain: "global"
```

Is there any way to obtain this information in real time, or at least from the same day of the request?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quota is available via both the Drive api about.get() API call:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

As well as via standard IMAP QUOTA command.

Comment: Yup, I had finally solved it with Drive API. Thank you.